# Too many parallel nested transactions

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
Location:    lckmgr.cpp:385
Expression:  0
SPID:        94
Process ID:  3752
Description:     Too many parallel nested transactions
```

my script has many table to left out join, and there is one table left out join itself, which tabel has 2,100,000 records.When I run the script in the sql server 2005, it will return this error message:Too many parallel nested transactions.

How to deal with? Please give me some help. Thank you very much.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DW.HouseholdDetail H 
    ON H.HouseholdCompositionID = T.HouseholdCompositionID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T_IC_CODE TRole 
    ON H.TenancyRoleCode = TRole.Code_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    DW.HouseholdDetail RH 
    ON H.RelatedToClientCoreID = RH.ClientCoreID 
    AND RH.HouseholdCompositionID = H.HouseholdCompositionID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    T_IC_CODE RTRole 
    ON RH.TenancyRoleCode = RTRole.Code_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    #TenantErrM AS TE 
    ON T.TenancyAccountID = TE.TenancyAccountID
```

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN DW.HouseholdDetail H
              On H.HouseholdCompositionID=T.HouseholdCompositionID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN T_IC_CODE TRole
              On H.TenancyRoleCode=TRole.Code_ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN DW.HouseholdDetail RH
              On H.RelatedToClientCoreID=RH.ClientCoreID
             and RH.HouseholdCompositionID=H.HouseholdCompositionID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN T_IC_CODE RTRole
              On RH.TenancyRoleCode=RTRole.Code_ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN #TenantErrM AS TE
              ON T.TenancyAccountID=TE.TenancyAccountID

Comment: What is your build # / SP level? It may be a known bug with an existing fix. Is it generating mini-dumps when it throws the error? If so, does the mini-dump say anything about "GetLocalLockPartition"? If so, check out this KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940935

Comment: no. The #tenantErrm is ok. If I give more filter condition, it will not throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a known issue in SQL Server. [Please see the related Microsoft KB article 940935](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940935?wa=wsignin1.0), which recommends:

> The fix for this issue was first released in Cumulative Update 3.

Maybe you need install SQL2005 SP4. See [KB article 939537](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939537/LN) for details on updating.